# Pupulate table with data in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, select, insert-query

I have two databases

1. db1
2. db2

db1 has table **controller**  below the description of controller table.

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| interface_name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| store_number          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| file_seq_no           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| packet_seq_no         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_trans_start_date | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_trans_end_date   | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_extract_datetime | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| is_enabled            | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and same table description and additional column(date_opened) with different name available in database **db2** with name store table.

My job is to write a query based on below logic.

Point 1 : Fetch all store_number, date_opened from db2.store.

Point 2 : Fetch all store_number from db1.controller table into list.

Point 3 : Filter new store_number fetched from db2.store not present in db1.controller.

**For each of these new store_number**

insert default initial values for new stores, file_seq_number and packet_seq_number will be set as zero.

last_transaction_start_date , last_transaction_end_date , last_extract_timestampwill be store creation date ie db2.store.date_opened

enabled will be set as 1

Main query would be

```
Insert into db1.controller table values( store_number, 0, 0,$date_opened,$date_opened,
$date_opened,1);
```

Can any one please help me to complete this sql query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @JW, can you suggest me something to get it done?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This something what i did

> INSERT INTO db1.controller
>   (interface_name,store_number,file_seq_no,packet_seq_no,last_trans_start_date,last_trans_end_date,last_extract_datetime,is_enabled)
>   SELECT
>   'test',s.store_number,0,0,s.date_opened,s.date_opened,s.date_opened,'1'
>   FROM `db2`.`store` s where  s.store_number not in (select store_number
>   from db1.controller);

Answer (score 1):

You can get filtered data by two ways.

With the help of `subquery`

```
Select db2.store .* from db2.store  where db2.store.id not in(Select db1.controller.id from db1.controller)
```

Here all new data which is not present in db1.controller will be displayed. You can display same result With the help of join also.

```
 SELECT db2.store.* FROM  db2.store  LEFT JOIN db1.controller ON db2.store.ID = db1.controller.ID WHERE db1.controller.ID IS NULL
```

You will get the data which is not present in `db1.controller` now iterate the data and execute your insert query.

**Update**

You can try below single query to add filtered records.

```
Insert into db1.controller (id,interface_name,store_number,file_seq_no,packet_seq_no,last_trans_start_date,last_trans_end_date,last_extract_datetime,is_enabled)  SELECT db2.store.id, db2.store.interface_name, db2.store.store_number, 0, 0, db2.store.date_opened, db2.store.date_opened, db2.store.date_opened, db2.store.is_enabled  FROM  db2.store  LEFT JOIN db1.controller ON db2.store.ID = db1.controller.ID WHERE db1.controller.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need single query which will insert the filtered records into the db1.controller table.

Comment: hmm seems to be tough wait for some time, may community will help you.

Comment: @subodh added single query try that.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I am looking for something without using join query.

Comment: I am giving you +1 for your effort.